# javascript regex doesn't work with RegExp

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, regex

Try to use node read a file and use regex to do something

```
const langFiles = 'test.php';
const fs = require('fs');

    const data = fs.readFileSync(langFiles, 'utf8');
    var pat = "\".*\.\w+\"" ;
    var rex = new RegExp( pat, "gim" ) ;
    var rep = "$1" ;
    var res = data.replace( rex, rep ) ;
    console.log( res ) ;
```

My regex already correct but my console result show the entire file, it seems it didn't execute the regex? `test.php` look like this https://pastebin.com/YFUD6AiE

Comment: try this, pat = /\".*\.\w+\" /

Comment: \ must be protected in RexExp : (new RegExp("\w+", "gmi")).test("hello moto"); // false, (new RegExp("\\w+", "gmi")).test("hello moto"); // true,